# Prevent the ModalDialog from formatting my strings

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I want to prevent the ModalDialog from formatting my strings

I have multiple text snippets that look similar to

```
const  p = "\"_id\": " + "\"\"" + ",\n " + 
             "\"name\": " + "zzInheritanceBaseElements" + ",\n " +
             "\"style\": " + "@settings {\n  include: person, loop;\n}\n\n/* Persons */\nelement[\"element type\"=\"person\"] {\n  icon: user;\n  icon-color: #c29999;\n  padding: 0;\n  color: #D57C2D;\n}\n\nelement[\"element type\"=\"Person\"] {\n  icon: user;\n  icon-color: #c29999;\n}\n\nelement:focus {\n  shadow-size: 1.9;\n  shadow-color: #e1eab6;\n  shadow-opacity: 1;\n}\n\nelement[image] {\n  icon: false;\n  size: 130;\n}\n\nelement[!image] {\n  size: 130;\n}\n\n" + 
    "},"
```

When I open them in the Modal I get

```
  "_id": "",
 "name": zzInheritanceBaseElements,
 "style": @settings {
  include: person, loop;
}

/* Persons */
element["element type"="person"] {
  icon: user;
  icon-color: #c29999;
  padding: 0;
  color: #D57C2D;
}

element["element type"="Person"] {
  icon: user;
  icon-color: #c29999;
}

element:focus {
  shadow-size: 1.9;
  shadow-color: #e1eab6;
  shadow-opacity: 1;
}

element[image] {
  icon: false;
  size: 130;
}

element[!image] {
  size: 130;
}

},
```

I am trying to create a string by concatenating multiple strings together then downloading it from the ModalDailog with

```
<script>
  const formatYmd = date => date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        formatYmd(new Date()); 
  const filename = "Kumu" + "_" + formatYmd(new Date()) + ".json"; // If you want to change the filename, please modify this.
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = <?= temp ?>;
  a.click();
  google.script.host.close();
</script>
```

I need the resultant string to be in the `original format`

How to prevent the ModalDialog from formatting my strings

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, by guessing your goal from your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to download your variable of `p` as a text file using Google Apps Script and dialog.
- You want to keep the text of the variable as follows.

  ```
    "\"_id\": \"\",\n \"name\": zzInheritanceBaseElements,\n \"style\": @settings {\n  include: person, loop;\n}\n\n/* Persons */\nelement[\"element type\"=\"person\"] {\n  icon: user;\n  icon-color: #c29999;\n  padding: 0;\n  color: #D57C2D;\n}\n\nelement[\"element type\"=\"Person\"] {\n  icon: user;\n  icon-color: #c29999;\n}\n\nelement:focus {\n  shadow-size: 1.9;\n  shadow-color: #e1eab6;\n  shadow-opacity: 1;\n}\n\nelement[image] {\n  icon: false;\n  size: 130;\n}\n\nelement[!image] {\n  size: 130;\n}\n\n},"
  ```

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function openDialog() {
  const p = "\"_id\": " + "\"\"" + ",\n " +
    "\"name\": " + "zzInheritanceBaseElements" + ",\n " +
    "\"style\": " + "@settings {\n  include: person, loop;\n}\n\n/* Persons */\nelement[\"element type\"=\"person\"] {\n  icon: user;\n  icon-color: #c29999;\n  padding: 0;\n  color: #D57C2D;\n}\n\nelement[\"element type\"=\"Person\"] {\n  icon: user;\n  icon-color: #c29999;\n}\n\nelement:focus {\n  shadow-size: 1.9;\n  shadow-color: #e1eab6;\n  shadow-opacity: 1;\n}\n\nelement[image] {\n  icon: false;\n  size: 130;\n}\n\nelement[!image] {\n  size: 130;\n}\n\n" +
    "},";

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index'); // Please modify this to your HTML filename.
  template.temp = `data:${MimeType.TEXT_PLAIN};base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(p))}`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template.evaluate(), 'sample');
}
```

- When this script is run for your Javascript, a text file including the above text data is downloaded.

Comment: I tried for hours and hours to figure this out.  Thank you!

Comment: @Einarr Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.